# reading data from an input file and storing it into a struct array

Tags: c, struct, io

I plan on reading an input file that has a name and a number separated by an indent such as

```
Ben     4
Mary    12
Anna    20
Gary    10
Jane    2
```

and then later perform a heap sort on the data. I'm having trouble copying the data and storing it into a struct array however.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define maxcustomers 100

struct customer{
    char name[20];
    int service;
};

int main()
{
    struct customer list[maxcustomers];
    int i;
    char c;

    FILE *input;
    FILE *output;
    input = fopen("input-file.txt","r");
    output = fopen("output-file.txt","w");

    if(input == NULL){
        printf("Error reading file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        printf("file loaded.");

    }
    while((c=fgetc(input))!=EOF){
           fscanf(input, "%s %d", &list[i].name,&list[i].service);

           printf("%s %d", list[i].name,list[i].service);
           i++;
    }
    fclose(input);
    //heapsort(a,n);
    //print to output.txt
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

so far it registers it opens a file and prints "file loaded" but fails after. im obviously not saving data to the struct.

Comment: @chrisaycock "you'll need `"%s\t%d"` instead of `"%s %d"` --> No.  `'\t'` and `' '` both match any white-space and _neither_ are needed here as `%d` consumes leading white-space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are consuming/walking the file with both `fgetc` and `fscanf`, use only `fscanf`:

```
while (fscanf(input, "%19s %d", list[i].name, &list[i].service) == 2) {
       printf("%s %d", list[i].name, list[i].service);
       i++;
}
```

Notice that you don't need the address of operator in `&list[i].name` because it is already (decays into) a pointer.

Comment: when compiling i get a warning: comparison between pointer and integer dealing with the == 2

Comment: @tanner, strange because `fscanf` returns an `int` not a pointer

Comment: i had not closed off the fscanfs parentheses it works now thank you.

Comment: @tanner, you are welcome, don't forget to initialize `i` as pointed out in the answer of @hellazari

Answer (score 3):

in addition to what @Keine Lust said,
`i` have no initial value, you cant use/increment integer without value as you did.

try: 
`int i=0`